# Azure container instance is still transitioning, please retry later

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Azure if failing when trying to start azure container instances.

`Failed to start the container group 'container-name'. Error: The container group 'container-name' is still transitioning, please retry later.`

Some other folks are also facing the same issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375744/the-container-group-is-still-transitioning-please

Any help?

In my case, these containers run every 30 min and I have them for a long time, this problem is pretty new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the link which you have shared with this question. Putting `-` in your container instance name does not gives any error. I tried adding `-` in my container instance name and it worked fine as below-
[image]
[image]

You can try isolating the issue from the activity logs or try deploying from a different region.
[image]

and look for error messages mentioned in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting)
You can also refer to [# container is still transitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375918/azure-container-instance-terminated-but-the-contai) solution by MSFT Eddie Neto

Comment: Thanks Naveen! Yeah, it was an issue in Microsoft, as we know it happens with everyone all the time. Mine ACI's started working again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the instance either with:

- Powershell: `Restart-AzContainerGroup -Name test-cg -ResourceGroupName test-rg`
- Azure CLI: `az container restart --name test-cg --resource-group test-rg`

[PS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/restart-azcontainergroup?view=azps-10.4.1)
[CLI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-restart)